# react native: state updates do not have effect on transform

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to have a component that gets bigger when pressed on, and gets smaller when released. I am trying to use `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` handlers to update state which updates the transform value:

```
const ExampleScreen = () => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  const scale = pressed === true ? 2 : 1;
  console.log('rendering with scale ', scale);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPressIn={() => setPressed(true)}
          onPressOut={() => setPressed(false)}>
        <View
          style={[
            {
              backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            },
            {transform: [{scale: scale}]},
          ]}>
          <Text>Press me</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I can see in the console that the state changes:

```
[Thu Jun 18 2020 19:36:14.483]  LOG      rendering with scale  1
[Thu Jun 18 2020 19:36:14.780]  LOG      rendering with scale  2
[Thu Jun 18 2020 19:36:15.124]  LOG      rendering with scale  1
```

but the square on the screen does not change its scale. Why is that, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Put this code outside your component like this

```js
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
}

const ExampleScreen = () => {/* your component */}
```

Then add this right before you update the state:

```js
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);

//Example
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPressIn={() => { 
                    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
                    setPressed(true);
                  }}>
```

For more info on LayoutAnimation go here: [LayoutAnimation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation)

Comment: thanks Lenni, but I don't want animation, I want instant scaleup and then instant scaledown, without transitions.

Comment: Oh sorry, then you shouldn't have any problem. I just tried your snippet and it works properly.